# QT QML: memory does not decrease when item is destroyed

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have dynamically created a qml page. 
I used a JS file to create it.
Then I have tried to destroy the created object. 
But I have observed that the amount of memory always increases instead of decreasing after the destroy call.

Comment: This explains it, same mechanism is in effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365996/memory-not-freed-after-calling-free

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Qt doesn't guarantee that Item will be removed instantly. You should expect real deletion later. 
How did you observe it? Did you look at virtual memory or physical memory? Do you understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347206/what-are-the-differences-between-virtual-memory-and-physical-memory)? And can you provide example?

Comment: @QtRosI write code for Android.I have installed an program which name is "OS Monitor". I observe memory for my program. I use Stackview. When I push stackview , memory increase But When I pop , memory never decrease. That is intresting , I use destroyOnPop property of Stackview . I push , and pop same page continuous for example , memory is never constans.  
constant. Memory increase. I use destroy qml page in onDestruction