# Why is the free memory not being reduced when i allocated 1GB of memory using Malloc

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

I have allocated 1GB of memory using malloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int *ptr = malloc(1024*1024*1024UL);
        if (ptr)
            printf("Memory Allocated\n");
        else
            printf("Allocation Failed\n");
        memset(ptr, 'a', (1024*1024*1024UL));
        getchar();
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
    }
```

Allocation is successful, but i don't see any difference in between the free memory.

Before running the application, my free memory:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           6906        1398        3457           7        2050        5206
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

After running the command, but before pressing enter on the keyboard at the getchar() stage.

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           6906        1398        3457           7        2050        5206
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

There is no change at all. So, from where is the memory allocated. It is virtual memory, but it should have a mapping into physical memory which is RAM. Can anyone explain this

Comment: perhaps it was optimized out, try checking the assembly generated

Comment: I think compiler has optimized your code avoiding the memory allocation. You can try compiling with `-O0` option and check.

Comment: Yes, after I compiled with -O0, i am getting the expected behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215259/608639), [Memory not freed after calling free()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5365996/608639), [Force free() to return malloc memory back to OS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27945855/608639), etc.