# Pushing back to a scoped std::vector< std::vector<double> > eventually uses up all memory

Tags: c++, stdvector

If you let the program below run undefinitely, it eventually uses up all RAM and the OS starts swapping (it took ~5 minutes to take up 64GB in my workstation).  If it is true what has been answered here: [When does the heap memory actually get released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024722/when-does-the-heap-memory-actually-get-released), then why does the OS go swap instead of reclaiming supposedly unused RAM?

As you can see in the code below, the large vector is supposedly to be freed by the end of each loop (goes out of scope).  So, I expected the program to occupy the same ammount of RAM all the time.

OBS: If you have less memory, you can set the `nIter` number to a lower figure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nIter = 700000000;
    while(true){
        std::vector< std::vector<double> > data;
        data.reserve(nIter);
        std::vector<double> dataLine( 7, 0.0 );
        for( int i = 0; i < nIter; ++i ){
            data.push_back( std::vector<double>() );
            data.back() = dataLine;
        }
    } //End of scope.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code has undefined behavior. It's an infinite loop with no observable behavior. See [process guarantees](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Progress_guarantee).

Comment: Are you sure it isn't failing on the first iteration? Edit : Your total memory requirement is at least 30 GB, at least on my platform.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux 7 (columns) * 8 (double) * 700,000,000 (lines) should give that figure, yes.  I didn't notice it, so I guess it's even more strange.  Well you can observe the result by monitoring resource consumption in your OS (`top` command in Linux, Task Manager in Windows, etc.)

Comment: I can't, because when I tried it, it failed the first time it tried to `data.reserve(700000000);`. Edit : You may simply be seeing the increase from each new element allocating it's data in the `for` loop. It likely runs out of RAM during that process in the first iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my machine.  Had to drop it to `7000000` though to get it to not throw a bad_alloc exception.  memory fluctuates up and down but doesn't slowly increase.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's what I was expecting: a constant memory consuption.  I'm running it on CentOS 6 64.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho If you change `nIter` to `7000000` like I did does it still increase or stay stable?

Comment: Works OK for me on CentOS 6.10 x86_64, with a smaller size. 700000000 throws `bad_alloc`

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess you nailed it.  It fluctuates between 80MB and 500MB.

Comment: My point is that I'm trying to figure out what was going on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388325/apparent-memory-leak-with-stdvector-of-stdvectors

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's a likely explanation as to why it fails later.