# How does Wt C++ call delete for allocated objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, delete-operator, wt

When looking at any given Wt C++ example, there are a lot of new calls but how do these even get deleted? Also, are these even guaranteed to be deleted and if so, when/where?

EDIT: This link pretty much answered how it's probably also done in Wt, although it doesn't directly speak about Wt.
[Why does the use of 'new' cause memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks)

Comment: Wt is free software. Look inside its source code!

Comment: Please check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116077/how-to-clean-up-memory-in-wt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean up memory in WT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116077/how-to-clean-up-memory-in-wt)

Comment: @NaseefUrRahman Thanks for the link but I actually already read that post. I didn't got a definitive answer to my question concerning new from it though. I'm mostly interested in knowing that it won't cause a memory leak - from the linked thread, it seems to be not the case, at least for return new HelloApplication(env);.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little *unsettling* to see `new`s without matching `delete`s..

Wt takes ownership of `Wt::Widget` pointers that are added to a page or widget hierarchy.  They are deleted automatically, as needed.

<s>Very soon</s> Now, a new **[Wt 4.0](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/news/2017/09/19/wt_4_0_0_is_here_)** release will clarify this by requiring you to *move* `std::unique_ptr`s to these functions, so it is unambiguous that you are transferring ownership.  Likewise, functions that *remove* widgets will return `unique_ptr`s to the calling code.

Comment: Thanks, it still stays a little bit vague for me but hope it really does clean it up.

Comment: Update: Wt 4.0 has been released.  (Link also updated)