# Is it possible that another program reuses free memory once allocated and later freed by other program already running?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, malloc, free

Let’s suppose that I have a Linux  (64 bits, Kernel 2.6, glibc 2.4) OS running on a machine with 8Gb of RAM. All referenced programs are C implementations.

Program A is started and let’s say that it allocates (and writes information inside) 5 Gb of memory (doing malloc). After this, it does free of all the preallocated memory. This means that we have a process that once used 5Gb of memory loaded in memory and now is running with very low memory usage.

While program A is still running and with no memory used, I start another instance of the same program (that I call Program B), trying to allocate 5Gb of memory.

What I am observing is that program B cannot reserve all the memory and OS starts to swap, although theoretically it should have enough free RAM. The conclusion is that Program A keeps the free 5 Gb of RAM for its own future usage and it cannot be used for any other program.

What does it happens to the freed memory by a program, from the point of view of the OS or any other program that needs to allocate a large amount of memory? Is there a way to force from OS to free this memory without stopping Program A?

Sorry for the oversimplification.

Thanks in advance!

PS: The code used is similar to this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int max = -1;
    int mb,x = 0;
    char* buffer[1000];

    if(argc > 1)
        max = atoi(argv[1]);

    while((buffer[mb]=malloc(50*1024*1024)) != NULL && mb != max) {
        memset(buffer[mb], 0, 50*1024*1024);
        mb++;
        printf("Allocated %d Mem Blocks, totalling %d\n", mb,mb*50);
        sleep(1);
        if((mb%15)==0)
    {
        for(x=0;x<5;x++)
        {   
        mb--;
                free(buffer[mb]);
            printf("Allocated %d Mem Blocks, totalling %d\n", mb,mb*50);
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More information: I have been requesting more information to the colleague that was having this problem. Seems that he omitted to tell me that he was doing the call from a JAVA program using JNI, so this changes absolutely the scenario. Maybe is a problem with JNI.

I will try to test on the next few days under such circumstances.

Sorry for the confusion :(

Answer (score 2):

See [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215259/will-malloc-implementations-return-free-ed-memory-back-to-the-system) for an explanation. If you actually strace your binary, you'll see that the memory is allocated using mmap(), but not freed, even if you call free().

Required is that free() gives back the memory to the process, not to the OS. WIth glibc, you can call malloc_trim(), but that only works with sbrk() allocated memory, not if the allocation is satisfied using mmap()

Comment: The question you linked (partially) disagrees with you, saying that large allocations are returned.

Answer (score 0):

In linux we use this command to free up the memory and dirty caches..

sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Hope this would help release the memory that is not being used.