# Understanding factors in latency bounded memcpy/memset x86_64

Tags: x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, memcpy, memory-bandwidth

I've been looking at some stackoverflow posts ([Why is std::fill(0) slower than std::fill(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558907/why-is-stdfill0-slower-than-stdfill1/45018779?noredirect=1#comment77014609_45018779) and [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy/43574756#43574756))  and one factor that determined the optimal memcpy/memset strategy appears to be whether the operation would be latency or DRAM bandwidth bound. One of the points was that `rep movsb` had a longer handoff latency than normal writes which I don't understand.

***Why does `ERMSB` `rep movsb` have longer handoff latency than a `movaps` (or any other normal write) loop for memcpy/memset***

[BeeOnRope commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558907/why-is-stdfill0-slower-than-stdfill1/45018779?noredirect=1#comment77014609_45018779) write:

> The behavior described above of rep movsb versus an explicit loop of movaps on a single core across various buffer sizes is pretty consistent with what we have seen before on server cores. As you point out, the competition is between a non-RFO protocol [Read For Ownership] and the RFO protocol. The former uses less bandwidth between all cache levels, but especially on server chips has a long latency handoff all the way to memory. Since a single core is generally concurrency limited, the latency matters, and the non-RFO protocol wins, which is what you see in the region beyond the 30 MB L3

In [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy/43574756#43574756), however, BeeOnRope says

> If you are concurrency limited, however, the situation equalizes and sometimes reverses, however. You have DRAM bandwidth to spare, so NT stores don't help and they can even hurt since they may increase the latency since the handoff time for the line buffer may be longer than a scenario where prefetch brings the RFO line into LLC (or even L2) and then the store completes in LLC for an effective lower latency. Finally, server uncores tend to have much slower NT stores than client ones (and high bandwidth), which accentuates this effect.

I am having trouble understanding how the non-RFO method (`rep movsb`) could have a longer latency handoff with the explanation for where latency handoff comes being whether the LFB (line-fill-buffer) has to handoff to cached memory in L2/LLC or to DRAM.

The [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy/43574756#43574756) post discusses the advantages of `rep movsb` on of which is:

> Issuing prefetch requests immediately and exactly. Hardware prefetching does a good job at detecting memcpy-like patterns, but it still takes a couple of reads to kick in and will "over-prefetch" many cache lines beyond the end of the copied region. rep movsb knows exactly the region size and can prefetch exactly.

Given that `rep movsb` is prefetching (more effectively than a `movaps` loop) wouldn't you expect a higher (or equal) likelihood that the LFB will be able to handoff to a line in at least L2/LLC compared to a `movaps` loop. If this is the case I don't understand:

> The former uses less bandwidth between all cache levels, but especially on server chips has a long latency handoff all the way to memory

particularly whether the long latency handoff is coming from.

so my questions are

1. ***where is extra handoff latency on the LFB in `rep movsb` coming from?***
2. ***more generally what contributes to latency bounds in `rep movsb` and memcpy/memset?***

Comment: I don't know if there's any similar effects on AMD, but I tagged this [intel] since the question is pretty specifically about recent Sandybridge-family microarchitectures.

Comment: its possible @BeeOnRope meant to be comparing NT stores vs normal stores in the paragraph where he discusses the longer handoff of the non-RFO stores.

Comment: No, he's clearly talking about the non-RFO stores `rep stos` does; that comment was posted before the edit that introduced a section about NT stores.  He might be intentionally generalizing to include NT stores as another way to do non-RFO stores, though, assuming that they will have similar tradeoffs.  (Although the OP's later test results didn't seem to support that: with a single thread and large buffers, apparently NT >> plain stores > ERMSB for whatever HW that was.)