# Is malloc'd data zeroed in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, security, malloc

I was wondering about this because it's a potential security hole if process A can malloc 50 megs of data that is not zero'd out and that chunk of memory turns out to include what had been physical pages from process B and still contain process B's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is malloc'd data zeroed in objective c?

Mostly Yes. There's a zero-page writer that is part of the memory manager which provides a *process* with zero'd pages. The memory manager will call `memory_object_data_unavailable` to tell the kernel to supply zero-filled memory for the region.

If the process calls `free` and then `mallocs` again, the page is *not* re-zero'd. Zeroization only occurs when a new page is demanded. In fact, the page is probably not returned to the system upon `free`. The process retains the page for its own use due to the runtime. Related, see [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215259/608639)

If a page is returned to the system under a low-memory condition, the the page will be re-zero'd even if the process formerly held the page. The memory manager does not account for last owner of a page. It just assumes a new page needs to be zero'd to avoid an information leak across processes.

Note Microsoft calls it the *zero-page writer*. Darwin has the same component, but I don't recall seeing it named. Also see [Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134426541) by Singh. Its a bit dated, but it provides a lot of system information. Chapter 8, Memory, is the chapter of interest.

Singh's book goes into other details, like cases where a page is demanded but does not need to be zeroized. In this case, there was some shared data among processes, and a new page was allocated to the process under a Copy-on-Write (COW) scheme. Effectively, the new page was populated from existing data rather than zero's. The function of interest is `memory_object_data_request`.

Linux has an interesting discussion of the zero page at [Some ado about zero](https://lwn.net/Articles/340370/). Its interesting reading about a topic that seems mundane on the surface.