# Get size of memory available on the heap

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, memory-leaks, heap-memory

This is platform dependent question for Linux. And if it matters, I'm asking specifically about pre-C++11.

I want to indirectly test a class's destructor by `new` and `delete` to see if all of the memory on the program's heap is deallocated, which could check for memory leaks.

```
object* x;        //pointer allocated on the stack
...               //measure available heap space
x = new object(); //allocated on the heap
delete x;         //deallocate that heap space
...               //measure again, see if it's the same
```

I understand that Valgrind has Massif (...is there a C++ library for Massif..?), and that I can even run a memory leak check on my entire program, but code changes. Unit tests are important, and it *bugs me to death* that I can't fully unit test all of my code.

What code can I write that would measure available heap space?

Comment: I'd say that's the wrong approach -- "*available*" heap space is not a constant over time. The memory mapped to your process will change, as the allocator calls OS specific APIs like `sbrk()` and `mmap()`. So what's "available"? Only what's currently mapped to your process? Or all memory your process *could possibly* get mapped? The latter is even more complicated (linux overcommits, btw). The other way around could work (but of course implementation dependent): measure the amount of *used* heap space.

Comment: All in all, you'd probably be "happier" doing what everyone else does: use unit testing for your actual business logic and look for memory handling errors using a tool like `valgrind` regularly (call it an *integration test*) ;)

Comment: Related, see Qualys [The Stack Clash](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2017/06/19/the-stack-clash) and [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215259/608639)

Comment: The typical solution is to run unit tests with [ASAN (address sanitizer)](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) or as you said yourself, under valgrind. I am not sure why you want to measure it from within the program. Just run a unit test that creates and deletes the object and then tell your test driver to run that test under valgrind.

Comment: If you want to be able to track your heap usage without running in a separate debug environment (i.e. you don't like running under valgrind for whatever reason), you can overload the C++ new and delete operators to track and report how many bytes of memory your program has allocated at any given time.  An example is here:  http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinction between stack and heap are somewhat vague in Linux.  Stack is just memory, the top of which, is handed to a `clone()` call which creates the new task.  This is true both for new processes and new threads.  The allocator operators are wrappers around system calls `brk`/`sbrk`.  Your best bet is to override the global `operator new`/`operator new[]` and `operator delete`/`operator delete[]` to do some sort of counting of the calls in such a way that you can examine it at run time.

A quick read through [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) can give you a good idea of order in which things happen when an object is created/destroyed (forgive me if you already know this) and [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) will tell the order in which allocators are looked up.  I may be wrong about this, but in order to have all allocators go through the same point of requesting memory from the OS, even the class-specific `operator new` would have to eventually call global `operator new`.

Well, the class-specific ones could use the allocator to `mmap` memory to a file or `shmget` to map the object to some storage in shared memory, but in both of those cases it wouldn't be part of what is traditionally referred to as "the heap."  The stack+heap both reside in what you see as "VIRT" memory when you run "top" in linux.

Short of that, the memory allocated by `malloc` and passed to the `clone` call (which, for instance, creates a new thread) to be the stack of a new thread will not be different from the memory used as heap.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'm still new to all of this, and I will definitely give them a read. I cede that I'm probably just looking for the wrong solution here, and I should probably do what @Ilya Popov suggested with Valgrind. Again, thanks for the answer.