# glibc application holding onto unused memory until just before exit

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leaks, glibc

I have a C++ application (gcc 4.9.1, glibc 2.17) running on Linux (Centos 7). It uses various third-party libraries, notably Boost 1.61. As the application runs, I can watch its memory usage increasing steadily via `htop`'s `VIRT` and `RES` columns, or the `ps` command, etc. If I let it go long enough, it will use enormous amounts of that memory and swamp the box.

Sounds like a leak, but it passes `valgrind` with only a few bytes leaked, all in places I'd expect. Debug print messages indicate program flow is as expected.

Digging further via the debugger, I find that most of this memory is still in use when `__run_exit_handlers` is invoked at the end of `main`. I can step through various calls to `free` as it works through the global destructor chain. After it finishes those, I observe only a minimal downward change in the apparent memory usage. Then, finally it calls `_exit()`, and only then is the memory restored to the operating system, all at once.

Can anyone offer me additional tips on how to proceed debugging this? Why won't my program give that memory back?

Comment: How do you know it's a memory leak, and not that your application is just memory intensive?

Comment: I don't think it is a leak. Note that this memory is still "in use" after my application's code is done running, and according to valgrind at least, has released all the memory it asked for.

Comment: @Ivan I'm not allocating many objects at all, but one of the 3p libraries I am using could be. I'm going to have to dig deeper there.

Comment: Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215259/will-malloc-implementations-return-free-ed-memory-back-to-the-system#3860495) about this.

Comment: Note that while it isn't technically a leak, it is possible to continue using more and more  memory. Maybe the program forgets to free it. Maybe memory fragmentation means lots of small free pieces that cannot be reused.

Comment: Why do you expect your program to "give memory back"? It is quite possible that there's no memory leak in your code, it is just that C++ run-time library keep holding on to memory requested from the system (since giving it back to OS and then re-requesting it is a relatively expensive operation). Why do you consider this to be a problem? I can see this being an issue on RAM-only systems (like Android), but this is a total non-issue on swap-enabled systems like desktop Linux.

Comment: @AnT I expect it to give back the memory it's no longer using. There is no leak in my application code. The problem is that glibc is not returning a resource to the operating system.

Comment: @John S: Well, again, why do you see it as a "problem"? Why are you concerned about it?

Answer (score 8):

Everything here is based on GNU libc implementation of `malloc` running on Linux.

Test program below does not seem to give away any memory to the system after freeing memory (`strace` does not show `sbrk` calls that return memory back to the kernel):

```
int main()
{
    static const int N = 5000000;
    static void *arr[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        arr[i] = std::malloc(1024);

    // reverse to simplify allocators job
    for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        std::free(arr[i]);
}
```

Looks like glibc does not give away memory back at all. According to [`mallopt(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) man page, parameter `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD` is responsible for giving away memory. By default it is 128kb, while test program allocates and frees 5 GB of memory. Looks like some other details of `malloc` implementation do not let it free memory.

At the moment I can recommend following solutions:

- If you can, try calling [`malloc_trim`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) once in a while or after freeing a lot of memory. This should force trimming and should give memory back to OS using `MADV_DONTNEED`.
- Avoid allocating large number of small objects using `malloc` or `operator new`, instead allocate them from a memory pool of a size greater than `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`. Try destroing that pool afterwards if program logic allows this. Memory chunks of size greater than `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` are immediately released back to OS.
- Same as previous one, but should be faster: allocate memory pools for small objects using `mmap` and release memory back to OS using [`madvise`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) and `MADV_DONTNEED`/`MADV_FREE`.
- Try using another allocator that might take advantage of `MADV_FREE` to return memory back to the system (jemalloc?).

---

I have found [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2531) old (2006) ticket on glibc's bugzilla. It says there that `free` never returns memory back to the kernel, unless `malloc_trim` is called.

Newer versions of `free` seem to have code that executes internal `systrim` function that should trim top of the arena, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: This is helpful. Periodic calls to `malloc_trim` largely reduced the amount of RES memory in use by the application, but not VIRT. I'm not allocating many objects in my own code, so one of the external libraries I'm using must be. I'm going to have to profile them, see if I can modify them to use a pool allocator in just the right spot.

Comment: @JohnS Virtual memory should not be such a big problem. The problem with `malloc_trim` is that might not free any virtual memory at all, instead it will use `madvise` with `MADV_DONTNEED` on free regions, replacing unused pages zero page. So OS gets its memory back, but changes in address space take time, reducing performance. `MADV_FREE` does similar thing, but should be faster since it remaps pages only under memory pressure.

Comment: The trim threshold is for *single allocations*. If an application uses 5 GB of 128 byte allocations, that doesn't get trimmed on free.

Comment: @ZanLynx That means since `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` is 128kb by default as well as `M_TRIM_THRESHOLD`, memory is never released with default parameters for small allocations.

Comment: @Ivan: That's right. The assumption is that future allocations will reuse those free memory bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can profile your memory allocation using `valgrind --tool=massif ./executable`

Check out the documentation at http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Then once you have profiling data you can apply memory pools and other techniques. Since you already use Boost you can find several such tools in Boost.