# htop shows memory still used even though deallocate was called

Tags: memory, fortran

```
mac osx (catalina)
gfortran 9.3.0 from homebrew
htop 2.2.0 from homebrew
```

I have the following program in `memtest.f90` which I compile with `gfortran memtest.f90 -o test` and then call with `./test`

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: n=100000000
  real, allocatable :: values(:)
  print *, "no memory used yet, press enter"
  read(*,*)
  allocate(values(n))
  values = 0.0
  print *, "used a lot of memory, press enter"
  read(*,*)
  deallocate(values)
  print *, "why is the memory still there in htop"
  read(*,*)
end program main
```

I am expecting the memory used by the program to drop after calling the deallocate statement, however, as indicated by `htop` it continues to hover at about 382 MB (see image below)

is this a memory leak and if so how do I properly release the memory or am I just doing something wrong in looking at the memory consumed by the program?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program will typically not return the memory to the operating system below some threshold. It may also take some time to be freed. This is not a Fortran issue, but rather a system issue.

I did not mark it as a duplicate of this [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215259/will-malloc-implementations-return-free-ed-memory-back-to-the-system) because it is quite indirect, and deserves some commenting, but the issue is there. Fortran compilers typically call the `malloc` provided by the operating system's or accompanying C-compiler's C library.

Comment: Fascinating.  I added an extra zero to N so that the program consumed ~4GB rather than ~400 MB and in that case it did return the memory to the system.  Thanks much