# why I use mutex protect std::queue in two thread, still memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, mutex

why I use mutex protect std::queue in two thread, still memory leak
Push is faster than pop, but push after 2000 times, push is stop, pop is always doing, when queue is empty, the memory of this program is 1.3GiB, memory leak
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tQFv.png)

```
class Test {
public:
    std::thread read_thread;
    std::thread write_thread;

    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<float>>> queue;
    void Init() {
        read_thread = std::thread(&Test::PushFunc, this);
        write_thread = std::thread(&Test::PopFunc, this);
    }

    void PushFunc()
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            usleep(1000 * 1);
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> a(mut);
            std::vector<float> sig;
            for (int i = 0; i < 752; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 480; ++j) {
                    sig.emplace_back(1.0f);
                }
            }

            queue.push(std::make_shared<std::vector<float>>(sig));
            std::cout << "push one\n";
            if (index++ > 2000) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void PopFunc()
    {
        while (true) {
            usleep(1000 * 25);
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            if (!queue.empty()) {
                queue.pop();
                std::cout << "pop one\n";

            } else {
                std::cout << "cannot pop\n";
            }

        }
    }


};


int main ()
{
    Test t;
    t.Init();
    while (true);
}
```

Comment: your code pushes ~25 times more often than pops. push: usleep(1000 * 1); pop: usleep(1000 * 25);

Comment: You have high memory usage but why do you think you have a memory leak?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: I see no leaking in the code. The program just keeps the allocated memory, in case you need it again later. Not immediately returning it back to the OS is an optimization.

Comment: Relevant: [Will malloc implementations return free-ed memory back to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2215259/580083). Many similar questions have been asked as well, just use you search engine to find them.

Answer (score 0):

thx to Daniel Langr, I used

```
malloc_trim(0);
```

solve this memory problem.

```
class Test {
public:
    std::thread read_thread;
    std::thread write_thread;
    std::thread clear;


    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<float>>> queue;
    void Init() {
        read_thread = std::thread(&Test::PushFunc, this);
        write_thread = std::thread(&Test::PopFunc, this);
        clear =  std::thread(&Test::ClearFunc, this);
    }

    void PushFunc()
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            usleep(1000 * 1);
            auto p = std::make_shared<std::vector<float>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 752; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 480; ++j) {
                    p->emplace_back(1.0f);
                }
            }
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> a(mut);
            queue.emplace_back(p);
            std::cout << "push one: " << queue.size() << "\n";
            if (index++ > 2000) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void PopFunc()
    {
        while (true) {
            usleep(1000 * 25);
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
            if (!queue.empty()) {
                queue.pop_front();
                std::cout << "pop one: " << queue.size() << "\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "cannot pop\n";
            }
        }
    }

    void ClearFunc()
    {
        while (true) {
            sleep(1);
            malloc_trim(0);
        }
    }
};
```